# Is there a way to count unique numbers and count unique text+numbers

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

For example:

```
Column A

1234
4567
2345
4356
a123
b345
c567
```

What formula to use so that when I count row 1-7, I get 4 counts of numbers and 3 counts of text+numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(A1:A))
```




```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IF(ISNUMBER(UNIQUE(A1:A)), 1, )))
```




```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IF(ISTEXT(UNIQUE(A1:A)), 1, )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! You just saved my life, bow down and kneel to you, respect!

Comment: @urgent123678 https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Interesting. Coul dyou explain `A1:A` ? i would understand `A1:A7`, but what does `A1:A` mean ?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez `A1:A` means from A1 to infinity